# How I can open a new Activity from a Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm experiencing some kind of troubleshooting and I tried look for similar answers here but did not find any.

```
public class TicketFragment extends Fragment {

    public Button strandard;
    public Button premium;
    public Button vip;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket, container, false);

    }

    public void openMainPage(){
        strandard = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.strandard);
        strandard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Payment.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

How I can call this method? Since this is a fragment, if I simply put it on the `onCreateView` method, it says that the statement is unreachable (if I put it before the return method it gives me an error when I lunch the project).

Comment: what is the logcat error when you puts it before the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class TicketFragment extends Fragment {

public Button strandard;
public Button premium;
public Button vip;
public View rootview;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket, container, false);

openMainPage();
 return rootview;

}

public void openMainPage(){
    strandard = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.strandard);
    strandard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Payment.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
}
```

You need to findViewById() from the view inflated by the fragment so therefore you should equate the rootview to the inflated view then find views within it by using `rootview.findViewById(R.id.strandard)`.

`openMainPage()` should be called before `return rootview` otherwise it will be inaccessible

Comment: Thanks @T.Mas, unfortunately it returns a NullPointJavaException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference.

Comment: @khegrfherhfqhre it's important that you follow the exact order within the code. Please make sure that the Button you are trying to access (R.id.standard) is indeed located within the layout fragment_ticket

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling openMainPage() anywhere inside your fragment, therefore not setting your click listener. You should do it in `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, unfortunately it returns a NullPointJavaException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference.

Comment: I do not understand why since this error occurs when I click the button